# Deleted user attempts to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I'm testing my rails app and I delete a user and try to login I get. Couldn't find user with `auth_token = " ... "`. Okay, I guess I create a cookie with an `auth_token` for the user which no longer exists.

How can I get my app to delete the cookie if user no longer exists, and where would I put that code?

**Sessions Controller**

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def new
   end

   def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email].downcase, params[:password])
       if user
         if user.email_activation_token == true
           if params[:remember_me]
             cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
           else
            cookies[:auth_token] = user.auth_token
           end
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
         else
           flash.now.alert = "You email has not yet been verified. Please click the link in your email." 
           render "new"
         end
      else
        flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
        render "new"
      end
   end

   def destroy
     cookies.delete(:auth_token)
     redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
   end
 end
```

**Users Controller**

```
  def self.authenticate(email, password)
   user = find_by_email(email)
   if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
   else  
    nil
  end
end
```

**application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user

  def handle_unverified_request
    sign_out
    super
  end


private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end

  def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you plz list user authentication code where auth_token is used for authentication?

Comment: ^ Added it in the edit

Comment: not this one, but somewhere you have used User.find_by_auth_token, right after the user login.

Comment: Oh i have that in the application controller. Just added it in update.

Comment: just use @Shadwell answer, that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete from the cookie. You are using `find_by_auth_token!` which will raise an exception if the user cannot be found. If you use `find_by_auth_token` without an exclamation mark then the call will return nil if no user can be found for the auth token and `@current_user` will be nil.